# Validating array fields based on index in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, date, laravel-5

I have two arrays in my request:

```
from = ["Dec 24,2017",.....]
to   = ["Dec 21,2017",....]
```

And I have added rules in **Laravel Validator** for them

```
'from.*' => 'required',
'to.*' => 'required',
```

But now I have to add a new validation rule. The first element in "from" must be less than or equal to first element in "to", and respectively for other elements in the arrays.

```
from[0] <= to[0];
from[1] <= to[1];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not just use a if loop to check each dates

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet,

```
$date = ["Dec 24,2017", "Dec 24,2017","Dec 24,2017","Dec 24,2017"];
$date1 = ["Aug 24,2017", "Dec 26,2017","Feb 24,2017","Nov 24,2017"];

foreach($date as $k => $val){
    if(strtotime($date[$k]) > strtotime($date1[$k])){
        return false;
    }
}
```

and you can also write custom validation, and keep above code inside that.

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, there is no way to create a custom validation comparing two variables. The answer you provided is the best solution.